# F# missing LINQ functions

Tags: .net, linq, f#

I'm trying to get LINQ working properly in my F# application (based on the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx). However, it seems that some properties and functions are missing.

For example if I try to add the following line:

```
db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
```

I get an error message: The field, constructor or member 'Log' is not defined.

Similarly there are functions missing such as InsertOnSubmit and InsertAllOnSubmit. I've managed querying the database, but at the moment I can't insert anything if these functions are missing.

Example code:

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

type internal dbSchema = SqlEntityConnection<"Data Source=localhost;Initial catalog=testDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out // Failure: Log not defined.
    let names = [|"Foo"; "Bar"|]
    let newVals = 
        [ for name in names -> new dbSchema.ServiceTypes.Items(Name = name) ]

    db.Items.InsertAllOnSubmit(newVals) // Same with InsertAllOnSubmit.

    0
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: The above code works for me.  (Obviously, I had to substitute the reference to the `Items` table with something that exists in my test database.)  What version of F# are you using?  If it makes any difference, I don't use `Integrated Security=SSPI`.  I have `User ID=[MY_USER_ID];Password=[MY_PASSWORD]`.

Comment: I'm using F# 3.0 with .NET 4.5. Created a new user in the database, gave it a sysadmin role, but the problem persists.

Comment: Does the rest of rest of the code work for you if you comment out the problematic `Log` line?  Can you check with `SQL Server Management Studio` that the `newVals` list is being entered?

Comment: The InsertAllOnSubmit isn't defined anywhere either. However I can write queries to list the rows in the Items table, it just looks like some functions are missing from the library.

Comment: It seems to me that you are not being able to access the database from your code.  Are you sure that your `SQL Server` instance is the default instance, and not a named instance?  Can you try using `COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `localhost`?  Do you have an `sa` account password for your database?  Can you try using that?

Comment: Finally, instead of `SqlEntityConnection` can you just try `SqlDataConnection` for a second and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, that did it. It should've been SqlDataConnection instead of SqlEntityConnection. No idea how that got there, but thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can also try using `SqlEntityConnection`, but you need to `open System.Data.Entity` at the top.

Comment: Nope, only works with SqlDatConnection.

Comment: @Shredderroy could you post the answer so we can move this question from an open state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mydogisbox Okay, here goes:

In the line:

```
type internal dbSchema = SqlEntityConnection<"Data Source=localhost;Initial catalog=testDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
```

try using `SqlDataConnection` instead of `SqlEntityConnection`.  That should work.